# I bought a product of 100$ at INR 7000 and did refund. Now I got INR7100 . From where INR 100 came?

Tags: india, currency

I know this must have happen due to the fluctuation of dollar rate with respect to INR. But the point is that 'I got INR 100 extra and company refunded only 100$. So company is not in loss I am in profit. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bought the product, the company wanted $100 USD. But because you didn't have USD, it charged you INR. In order to determine how much INR to pay, the conversion rate on that day was used. (I'm not sure if you sent INR to the company, or if you used your bank's website to send USD using the bank's conversion feature.) So it looks like the conversion rate on that day was 70 INR = 1 USD, and you sent 7,000 INR.

Then later on, the INR weakened, and the USD strengthened. (The volatility in the market recently has made people generally want the 'safety' of the USD currency, so the USD strengthened compared with most currencies globally, as often happens in times of trouble.) Now, it would take 71 INR to buy 1 USD.

When you ask the company for the refund, they basically don't care how much INR you paid, they care about the USD amount they received. So they received 100 USD, they will return USD. And somewhere down the line, that 100 USD was sold to buy INR to send to you. (Probably the company sent USD to your bank, and your bank converted it to INR on your behalf.) Because the USD was stronger, it bought 7100 INR instead of 7,000, and that is why you received more INR back than you paid.

Imagine instead of buying a product and having it returned, you simply bought $100 USD from a currency exchanger at a cost of 7000 INR, and then sold the USD back a week later for 7100. The reason you get more back is that you take on the risk of fluctuations in between the two currencies. If the USD had weakened instead, you might have gotten back only 6900 or less INR.

Comment: Thanks Grade 'Eh' Bacon for the detailed explanation. :)

Comment: @Lawrence Ah yes, that typo of mine was actually just a.. uhhh... local dialect.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you didn't gain 100 INR.

The FX fluctuations - theoretically - represent Purchase power of the currency. Ie. how much things a currency can buy in exchange. the higher the purchase power, the stronger the currency.

The 100 INR that you got higher - is on account of INR's weakening of purchase power. When you paid 7000, and got back 7100, the inherent purchase power remained the same. So, you didn't gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Currency works the same way as stocks or gold etc do. You "bought" $100 at some point in time and you "sold" the $100 later in time. During the time when you owned the $100 the price for dollars went up, so you made a profit. If the price would have dropped you would have made a loss.